# How to handle dynamic slugs with express?

Tags: json, express, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to handle dynamic slugs such as:`mydomain.com/foo` with express and axios in Nuxt.

I had it working prior with dynamic slugs if they were integers (/1, /2, /3, etc..) but when I try to take the same logic and match it with the json object I am having trouble.

Expected: 
When user inputs a url like `mysite.com/randomslug` the router will check the slug for a match in the JSON object. If match is found, then it will send the data as a result, if the match is not found then it will send a 404 status.

Here is my code: 
Within my /api/skateparks.js file:

```
// Skateparks
const skateparks = {
  'toronto': {
    'name': 'toronto',
    'address': 'ontario',
    'city': 'ville'
  },
  'aurora': {
    'name': 'aurora',
    'address': 'ontario',
    'city': 'hello'
  },
  'ajax': {
    'name': 'ajax',
    'address': 'ontario',
    'city': 'hell'
  }
}
console.log('hello world')
/* GET skatepark listings. */
router.get('/skateparks', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json(skateparks)
})

/* GET skatepark location  */
router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  let id = req.params.id
  for (let skatepark in skateparks) {
    if (skatepark === id) {
      res.json(skateparks[id])
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404)
    }
  }
})
```

Within my `/pages/_id.vue/` file:

```
<script>
import axios from '~/plugins/axios'

export default {
  name: 'id',
  asyncData ({ params, error }) {
    return axios.get('/api/skateparks')
      .then((res) => {
        return { skatepark: res.data }
      })
      .then(console.log, console.log)
      .catch((e) => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: params })
      })
  },
  head () {
    return {
      title: `User:`
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Edit: Ran into some luck with the updated get function. 
Still not working quite right as its only pulling data from some of the objects but not all

Comment: You have a small number of legitimate parks-- enumerate the failures please. What happens when you GET `mysite.com/toronto` vs `mysite.com/aurora` vs `mysite.com/ajax`?  More information on the failures in _specific_ circumstances would be very helpful...